# pkg-config doesn't recognizing any options for some reason

Tags: package-management, pkg-config

I'd like to use pkg-config to change the include dirs for a package, but it looks like it doesn't accept any options.

After issuing the following command:

```
pkg-config --cflags ImageMagick -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6
```

...it instantly fails right at the first cflag option:

```
Unknown option -fopenmp
```

Is this a normal behavior? How can I make it work?

PS: Using Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pkg-config` outputs flags intended to be used with a compiler or linker. Typically you’d use it like this:

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags ImageMagick) …
```

You can’t use the `pkg-config` command to change the paths used by a given package. The paths are defined in the corresponding `.pc` file, *e.g.* `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ImageMagick.pc`. To customize that, the safest option is to copy that file somewhere else, modify it as appropriate, and specify the path to the file using the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable.

Note that if you built the ImageMagick libraries yourself, the build should have produced a valid `.pc` file for you. You also shouldn’t use `.pc` files to specify options such as `-fopenmp`; those shouldngo in your build command, in your makefile or in the `CPPFLAGS`, `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS` environment variables (or makefile variables).

Comment: Thanks, It wasn't clear at first glance.
In fact, I'm trying to compile a program that uses the imagemagick libraries, but some of the headers can be found in a different location (that's why I'm trying to change the path in particular). Unfortunately, the build doesn't producing any .pc files, and I have no idea how make `make` search for that header file in a another directory (nor how the .pc syntax works).

Comment: I recommend asking another question explaining what your end goal is, proceeding in this way is probably barking up the wrong tree!

Comment: That's what I'm going to do, thanks again for your time!